# How do I list modules on my site that are not covered by the Drupal security advisory policy?

Tags: 7, drush

We have a number of contributed modules installed on a Drupal 7 site, but there doesn't seem to be an easy way to see those covered by the Drupal security advisory policy, without copy-pasting each module name into the address bar and manually checking the page.

Is there a way to do this with Drush?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a report (a good home for such a thing might be the [Site Audit project](https://www.drupal.org/project/site_audit)? ([#2882555](https://www.drupal.org/node/2882555))

Here's a *very* quick report for D7 that shows:

- Custom modules
- Modules without a release covered by Security Policy

You can download this and use it with `drush scr`, or copy it for `drush eval` directly. [Feel free to improve on it!](https://gist.github.com/xurizaemon/666985e555a7c0afb00e890ff441cb0b)

```
<?php
$projects = update_get_available(true);
$uncovered = [];
foreach ($projects as $name => $project) {
  if (!isset($project["releases"])) {
    $uncovered[$name] = "No releases found";
  }
  else {
    $latest_release = reset($project["releases"]);
    if (!empty($latest_release["security"])) {
      $uncovered[$name] = $latest_release["security"];
    }
  }
};
print_r($uncovered);
```

Comment: I don't have time to improve the code right know, but I can at least report that it doesn't work. Modules that have stable releases (covered by the security advisory policy) will be reported as uncovered by the script if they have a alpha release for the next version. This can be confirmed by testing the script with the Media module. In addition the script should check if a stable version is in fact installed ...

Comment: Thanks @hansfn, good point: code above assumes we're checking the *latest* release is covered by security release. I'll leave as is, improvements welcome! (Happy to update answer from the [linked issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2882555) or [gist](https://gist.github.com/xurizaemon/666985e555a7c0afb00e890ff441cb0b).)

Comment: Howdy, I'm the Site Audit author, happy to include that functionality in there. I honestly don't want to maintain a list, but leveraging drush & update_get_available sounds like a great solution. Will follow-up more in the issue.